# How do you align 270deg rotated text to top left?

Tags: html, css, transform, alignment

This should be a very simple problem you would think. I have a box with some title text that I want to rotate -90 degrees. I would like it to be absolutely positioned so that the end of the word is nudged into the top left corner. I can get this to align to the bottom easily enough, but the problem is that with variable length text it seems impossible to have it consistently stay within the container when aligning to the top because things like `{top: 0}` operate on the title before the transform. For my purposes this only needs work in Firefox. I can use javascript if that is the only solution, but you would think this could be done with just CSS.

Comment: Can you show what you have so far using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Just for the simple reason that I can't be bothered recreating what you already have :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lomacar/jCaKM/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should use [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform-origin) to adjust the transformation point, along with some creative use of positioning properties.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/JxEfs/1/

**CSS:**

```
#box {
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#box > div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: right top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: right top;
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform-origin: right top;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform-origin: right top;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
    hello
    <div>rotated!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. I explained that the problem has to do with the order of the rotation and alignment operations.

Comment: I made a fiddle but you were too fast! Thanks, that is a clever solution with `{right:100%}`. You should edit your answer with this solution. I came up with a solution involving wrapping a transformation div around the title and rotating the title 180deg. Your's is much more elegant.

Comment: +1, thanks that's awesome, I used this code but changed the `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;` to keep the text on screen.

Answer (score 16):

Can also work without right:100%
Just rotate 270 deg around left top and then translate it back at new 100% width.

```
transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0);
transform-origin: 0 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zW7SP/

Comment: There's a slight catch with this if your text is wider than the width of the page. For example if you were trying to do this on a phone the text would take on the width of the phone, then when rotated it would wrap - as opposed to filling the screen height. There's a number of solutions depending upon your exact needs but for a single line of text you can just add `width: 100vh; text-align: right;`