# transform(270deg) width and left css issue for horizontal accordion

Tags: html, css

Im creating a horizontal accordion and I'm having a problem with the width, left and top positions. What I want is the h3 tag to fill the entire height of the accordion after the transformation so I'm using the width to 100% but it messes up the accordion and the h3 tags are not next to each other there is a gap in between each tab. If someone knows to setup my elements to be aligned next each other and no gaps and the position of the top is alignment that would be great. You can use different elements if you want Im just using h3 after doing a tutorial here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaKe/)

html:

```
<div class="accordian" data-type="horizontal">
<h3 id="special_offers">Special Offers</h3>
<div></div>
<h3 id="new_products">New Products</h3>
<div></div>
<h3 id="reduced_to_clear">Reduced To Clear</h3>
<div></div>
<h3 id="coming_soon">Coming Soon</h3>
<div></div>
```

css:

```
accordian {
height:300px;
}
.accordian h3, .accordian div {
display:block; float:left;  position:relative
}
.accordian h3 {
padding:6px
}
.accordian h3{
-webkit-transform:rotate(-270deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(-270deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-270deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
}
.accordian #special_offers {
background:#C90;
}
.accordian #new_products {
background:#C60;    
}
.accordian #reduced_to_clear {
background:#C30;    
}
.accordian #coming_soon {
background:#C00;    
}
```

Comment: have you looked at this http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jQuery-common-accordion

Answer (score 0):

The biggist confusion is that by rotation a div, width becomes height and height becomes width. Besides that there is an selector available on which corner the div should turn (also see [How do you align 270deg rotated text to top left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668703/how-do-you-align-270deg-rotated-text-to-top-left) ).

I set up an example with the height = width 
http://jsfiddle.net/SpaKe/2/
as you can see all things work out quite nice

Now if you want to make a rectangle of 300px high and lets say 50px wide, and you want to align the divs next to each other. Then you have to introduce margin-right: -xxx px . Then calculate the diffrence between height- width = 250px. So margin-right:-250px; should do the trick.

again an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/SpaKe/5/
As we can see here, it works in most browsers (At the moment I'm not able to test IE behavior)

```
.accordian h3{
width:300px;
    height:50px;
    margin-right:-250px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-270deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-270deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -o-transform: rotate(-270deg);
    -o-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform: rotate(-270deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

So rember: width and height are changed when rotation, you can set the corner on which the div should be rotated on.